# MySQL password input in bash script

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a bash script that needs to perform a couple actions in MySQL.  So far I have something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
read -p "Enter your MySQL username: " $sqluname
read -sp "Enter your MySQL password (ENTER for none): " $sqlpasswd
/usr/bin/mysql -u $sqluname -p $sqlpasswd << eof
*some SQL stuff*
eof
```

This works well until it's used with a MySQL username that has a blank password.  The user hits ENTER at my password prompt, but then they receive another prompt to "Enter your password" again from MySQL.

How can I avoid this second password prompt and make the script deal with both blank and non-blank passwords?

Comment: Does it work if you replace `$sqlpassword` with `"$sqlpassword"`?

Comment: Nope....................

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the password is blank or not, and if it is, then omit the -p switch altogether.

```
read -p "Enter your MySQL username: " $sqluname
read -sp "Enter your MySQL password (ENTER for none): " $sqlpasswd
if [ -n "$sqlpasswd" ]; then
  /usr/bin/mysql -u $sqluname -p $sqlpasswd << eof
else
  /usr/bin/mysql -u $sqluname << eof
fi
```

Later edit to avoid a whole if-then-else block:

```
command="/usr/bin/mysql -u $sqluname"
[ -n "$sqlpasswd" ] && command="$command -p$sqlpasswd"
eval $command
```

Comment: That will work.  I was kinda hoping there was a tidier way than an if/then/else block, but this works fine anyway.

Comment: Hmm you could try this instead of the whole block if you want something shorthand:
[ -n "$sqlpasswd" ] && command = "$command -p$sqlpasswd"

Comment: +1 for the first variant; the second version feels like it is more trouble than it is worth.

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to specify the `-n` switch if $sqlpasswd is empty (instead of `-p $sqlpasswd`).